# Excel countif or if

Tags: excel, if-statement

Tried doing this a few ways and I think I'm just looking at this a little too complicated.

I have column a with several different names that repeat. I have column B with dollar amounts. I'm trying to get a formula that will add the totals amount for a specific person.

```
JOHN    $17.23 
JAMES   $37.52 
JOHN    $14.23 
JAMES   $27.52 
APRIL   $32.00 
APRIL   $143.20 
JOHN    $90.27 
JOHN    $81.13

JOHN = Total for John
JAMES = Total for James
APRIL = Total for April

Thank you
```

Comment: Have you tried `Pivot` table or `SumIf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this table

```
      A          B    
1    Names     Bill
2    John      10
3    Tom       20
4    John       4
5    Tom        3
```

To get the total for each name you can write

```
      A          B    
7    Names     Total
8    John      =Sumif(A2:A5;A8;B2:B5)
9    Tom       =Sumif(A2:A5;A9;B2:B5)
```

This will sum up each value for the given area.

Comment: I like this idea too.  It's the same, but even better than mine.

Comment: @durbnpoisn If you like it and find it usefull you can upvote it

Comment: Fair enough.  It's litterally is the same thing I did, but yours used the reference to the cell.  Actually a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$8="John")*(B$1:B$8))
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$8="James")*(B$1:B$8))
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$8="April")*(B$1:B$8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Striking my original response in favor of:
=SUMIF(B3:B10,"=JOHN",C3:C10) I tested that, and it works even better